# How to get the association lines to behave (and persist) in the EDMX designer?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx, edmx-designer

Whenever I open my .EDMX file for editing, the association lines connecting the various entities are different (and varying wildly) from how I left them when I last closed it.

Here's VS2013's latest drunken spree:

[image]

I've tried editing the Diagram XML, but still I've found no success against this.

For example, here's the XML for the longest misbehavior above:

```
<AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_InvoiceItems_Invoices" ManuallyRouted="true" >
  <ConnectorPoint PointX="2" PointY="11.875" />
  <ConnectorPoint PointX="6.5" PointY="11.875" />
</AssociationConnector>
```

It's pretty straightforward: we should be seeing just one straight horizontal line between Invoices and InvoiceItems. I have no idea how we ended up with *this* mess. I can drag it back into place, save it and close it, but as soon as I open the file up again it comes back.

Is anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: I would just like to add that this too is infuriating me, it's still going on in 2017 on simple 1 to many relationships

Comment: @Tod — they've taken down my bug report; as I recall they turned it down as "Won't fix."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I've decided that in its current iteration the EF designer simply isn't able to handle what I'm trying to throw at it. It appears to be a bit buggy yet.

So I've turned off `ManuallyRouted` in all elements and rearranged my Entities instead so that I don't get overlapping lines (which is what I was trying to accomplish in the first place).

There's far more important stuff in the world to worry about than this.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Almost 3 years later in VS2015 I'm also experiencing the same issues with the EF designer.  Nicely arranged diagrams become a mess of lines upon saving, closing then re-opening the same EDMX.

I came to the same conclusion - turn off ManuallyRouted, re-arrange the entities to get straight lines and move on.

Comment: @Jay — Are you in a position to consider switching to Code First? That would sidestep this problem neatly. I've done so in the time since and I haven't looked back.

Comment: For this project Code First is not an option, but thanks for offering the suggestion.